# Undefined Control Sequence \maketitle

Tags: titles, delimiters

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{headings}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering
% Set up the Title Page
\title  {SEMINAR NAME }
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{XYZ@gmail.com}{STUDENT NAME}}
            {STUDENT NAME}
            }
\addresses  {\ BACHELOR OF ENGINNERING\\\COMPUTER ENGINEERING \\\SAVITRIBAI PHULE PUNE UNIVERSITY}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {APRIL-MAY 2015}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}

\maketitle
\clearpage
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This seems to create an error at Line 32

At the

```
\maketitle 

Undefined control sequence. \maketitle
```

Any clue? It does generate PDF. Seems. But gives those errors. Works on ShareLatex. Not on TexMaker, Miktex 2.9

Comment: (1) always post full minimal examples. (2) what happens if you delete the aux and toc files and recompile?

Comment: Without having access to the actual `Thesis` document class, it's not possible to tell for sure what's going on. From where might one be able to obtain a copy of `Thesis.cls`? (The Internet is chock-full of sites with `thesis` and `Thesis` document classes. Which one is the one you use?)

Comment: probably not relevant to problem, but ... (1) `fancyhdr` is requested twice, and (2) `\hypersetup` is used without an evident loading of `hyperref` (but that may be built into `Thesis.cls`).

Comment: You are using a local Thesis class, it presumably has some documentation, perhaps the command to make the title is not `\maketitle`, that is not uncommon as thesis may have special requirements with multiple title and dedication pages and a thesis class may have specific commands, but you have the class and its documentation, we do not...

Comment: In its current state, the question cannot be answered since we don't have access to `Thesis.cls`. Please add some information to the question.

Comment: Isn't the title page set-up part of the header? Then you could try moving `begin{document}` just before `\maketitle`. Also, you have an extra space in your title parts of the addresses could be interpreted as commands. Well, anyways, I was just stopping by. Was actually looking for something else around here. kby